# Prove hyperbolic operator L is simply the wave operator in a coordinate system moving with velocity $-B/2A$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

This exercise comes from A First Course in Partial Differential Equations - H.F. Weinberger

8.2) Show that if the operator $L[u] = A(\frac{d^2u}{dt^2})+B(\frac{d^2u}{dxdt})+C(\frac{d^2u}{dx^2})$ is hyperbolic and $A$ does not equal 0, the transformation to moving coordinates $x' = x-(\frac{B}{2A})t$, $t' = t$, takes $L$ into a multiple of the wave operator.

The textbook gives no example of when or where to substitute these new coordinates into the operator, or what would justify a proof of this. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: @ Chieef:  Howdy there Chieef!  Nice.,question, +1!  By the way, what does "$A$ does not equal -" mean?  That $A$ is non-negative?  Or is something missing?